# How to use one display exclusively for one application?

Tags: windows, macos, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, window-manager

I regularly use virtualisation software. My most common use case is to have one monitor for the virtual system and one monitor for the physical system.

But of course, the physical system always puts other windows above or behind the virtual machine window. Is there a way to restrict the physical system to only use one monitor and put the VM on the other monitor?

Comment: What exact OS is the physical system running?  What's your virtualization software?  This might be relevant.

Comment: As hinted in the tagline, I the physical systems are mainly Windows and OSX. I use VirtualBox and VMWare Player and VMWare Fusion. But really, I want to constrain window movement. This should probably not be related to the VM software at all.

Comment: I read it as you were virtualizing one of Windows/OSX in the other.  (Windows 7?) Hence request to specify - nobody can recommend a solution without knowing the host after all.  (And the VM software could be relevant if it supports, say, true fullscreen or something.)

Answer (score 1):

Set up [Spaces](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#spaces) in the `System Preferences` > `Spaces` pref. You can assign a virtual system application to a specific space.

Comment: Interesting. Not exactly what I am looking for, but interesting!